# How to refresh CSRF Token per request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, csrf

I am building an App for a client, where they require a new csrf token per mutable request.
How can I enable this in rails?

Comment: Can you explain "per mutable request?" Perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @Substantial May be the OP meant all non GET request by that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the gem below as the tokens are invalidated after each request. If your client will be using Angular.js for the front-end, there's an Angular module that hooks right into it too!

Ruby Gem:  https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Angular.us model for tokens: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth

[Picture of the token Handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHtFF.jpg)